# how to run method in master page before execute child page code in IsPostBack?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have two buttons in  masterpage one for arabic language and for english 
when I click on one of  those buttons the session["Lang"] will change.

now in chiled page  I write this

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Session["Lang"] == "en-US")
    {
        Label1.Text = "English";
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Arabic";
    }
```

when I click on the button to change the session the code in child  will execute first then will go to master page   and run  a butn event  to change the session

Any one have any Idea to call the button event before child page

Thanks in Advance

Mohammmed ^_^

Comment: how about updating the session["Lang"] in child page itself.

Comment: but the button is based in masterpage ... how to change session["lang"] from child using same button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this method

```
 protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
}
```

in  this method I Got the event Target (ID of the button) ussing this

```
      protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
     string language = Request["__EventTarget"];
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(language))
        {
            if (language.EndsWith("Ar"))
            {
                languageId = "ar-SA";
            }
            else if (language.EndsWith("En"))
            {
                languageId = "en-US";
            }
       }
```

So the session will change frist then will load the page and then the master page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a look at the ASP.NET Webforms page lifecycle in order to understand what happens when.

Here is some docs regarding that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx#lifecycle_events

The problem you have at the moment is that the Button click event happens after the `Page_Load` event, so when you click the button you probably experience that `Label1.Text` is one click "behind".

Look at the docs and place the `Label1.Text` assignment in `PreRender` for example.

Like @ArabicProgrammer is answering, it is better yet to actually make use of the Culture support that is available in the .NET Framework. If you use that method instead, you can display the language using something like this.

```
<%= System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DisplayName %>
```

Instead of using a Label control.

Answer (score 1):

InitializeCulture is executed before page load, you should use it to change the culture of the page and in master page after execution redirect to default page.

You can use this

```
 protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Session["Lang"].ToString());
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Session["Lang"].ToString());
        base.InitializeCulture();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Arabic Programmer I use the same Faction with diffrent logic